# Can not establish mongodb connection from node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I made this node js app and then i tried with postman but every time i made a request that involves mongodb, it keeps loading. The function find of the model is where the code stops and the callback is never called.

app.js

```
var express = require("express"),
app = express(),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
methodOverride = require('method-override'),
mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Connection to DB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/users', function(err, res) {
  if(err) {
    console.log('ERROR: connecting to Database. ' + err);
  }
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());

var models = require('./models/user')(app, mongoose);
var userContoller = require('./controllers/user');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('GET');
   res.send("Hello World!");
});

app.use(router);

var users = express.Router();

users.route('/users')
  .get(userContoller.findAllUsers);

app.use('/api', users);

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Node server running on http://localhost:3000");
});
```

models/user.js

```
exports = module.exports = function(app, mongoose){

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userName:    { type: String },
  password:     { type: Number }
});

mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

};
```

controllers/user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User  = mongoose.model('User');

//GET - Return all tvshows in the DB
exports.findAllUsers = function(req, res) {
  console.log('llega');
    User.find(function(err, users) {
    if(err) res.send(500, err.message);

    console.log('GET /users')
        res.status(200).jsonp(users);
    });
};
```

The mongodb server is started through the console but i don't know how to check it.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I made the code easier for me to test and solve the problem.
The code now is this and im not getting the connection to mongodb.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', function() {
  console.log('error');
});
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('connected');
});
```

I don't get in the console the error or the connected.

In the mongod console i get some messages saying that a new connection was made. This happens every time i open the nodejs program.
Thanks

Comment: why jsonp ? Did you mean json ?

Comment: Is the express function to return a json

Comment: You can open the terminal and type `mongo` to check if mongo work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are giving call back to the mongoose.connect function. In my case i did:

```
mongoose.connect(url, options)
const db = mongoose.connection

db.on('error', function () { console.log('Cannot Connect to DB') })
db.once('open', function () { console.log('Mongoose Connected to DB') })
```

Also instead of:

`users.route('/users').get(userContoller.findAllUsers);`

You may try:

`users.get('/users', userController.findAllUsers);`

And I realized that you don't pass a `next` argument to your controller which express generally complains if you dont pass.

Edit:  I think i found the error.

When you are using the `.find` function you need to pass 2 arguments. In your case because you are not passing the callback as the second argument it never gets called.

`User.find({}, callback)`  should do it.

Comment: I updated the answer maybe you should check it. Cheers!

Comment: I edited the question, the problem seems to be on the mongoose connection

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The version of mongoose was older than the needed to connect to my mongodb version. Just update it via npm and good to go.

Comment: I am also getting the same error, my call still goes infinity, connection.readystate always give 2.
I did update the version now is 3.4.12.
I am using linux machine.